# How to search tweets?

Tags: .net, twitter, twitter-oauth

I implemented OAuth authentication and wanted to search for tweets using the following code:

```
private void searchTweetsWithQuery(string query)
        {
            var oauth_token = xxx;
            var oauth_token_secret = xxx;
            var oauth_consumer_key = this.context.ConsumerKey;
            var oauth_consumer_secret = this.context.ConsumerSecret;

            // oauth implementation details
            var oauth_version = "1.0";
            var oauth_signature_method = "HMAC-SHA1";

            // unique request details
            var oauth_nonce = Convert.ToBase64String(
                new ASCIIEncoding().GetBytes(DateTime.Now.Ticks.ToString()));
            var timeSpan = DateTime.UtcNow
                - new DateTime(1970, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, DateTimeKind.Utc);
            var oauth_timestamp = Convert.ToInt64(timeSpan.TotalSeconds).ToString();

            // message api details
            var status = "Updating status via REST API if this works";
            //var resource_url = "https://api.twitter.com/1.1/statuses/user_timeline.json";
            var resource_url = "https://api.twitter.com/1.1/search/tweets.json";
            var screen_name = "nikogamulin";
            // create oauth signature

            var baseFormat = "oauth_consumer_key={0}&oauth_nonce={1}&oauth_signature_method={2}" +
                            "&oauth_timestamp={3}&oauth_token={4}&oauth_version={5}";

            var baseString = string.Format(baseFormat,
                                        oauth_consumer_key,
                                        oauth_nonce,
                                        oauth_signature_method,
                                        oauth_timestamp,
                                        oauth_token,
                                        oauth_version
                                        );



            baseString = string.Concat("GET&", Uri.EscapeDataString(resource_url), "&", Uri.EscapeDataString(baseString));

            var compositeKey = string.Concat(Uri.EscapeDataString(oauth_consumer_secret),
                                    "&", Uri.EscapeDataString(oauth_token_secret));

            string oauth_signature;
            using (HMACSHA1 hasher = new HMACSHA1(ASCIIEncoding.ASCII.GetBytes(compositeKey)))
            {
                oauth_signature = Convert.ToBase64String(
                    hasher.ComputeHash(ASCIIEncoding.ASCII.GetBytes(baseString)));
            }

            // create the request header
            var headerFormat = "OAuth oauth_consumer_key=\"{3}\", oauth_nonce=\"{0}\", oauth_signature=\"{5}\", oauth_signature_method=\"{1}\", " +
                               "oauth_timestamp=\"{2}\",  " +
                               "oauth_token=\"{4}\", " +
                               "oauth_version=\"{6}\"";

            var authHeader = string.Format(headerFormat,
                                    Uri.EscapeDataString(oauth_nonce),
                                    Uri.EscapeDataString(oauth_signature_method),
                                    Uri.EscapeDataString(oauth_timestamp),
                                    Uri.EscapeDataString(oauth_consumer_key),
                                    Uri.EscapeDataString(oauth_token),
                                    Uri.EscapeDataString(oauth_signature),
                                    Uri.EscapeDataString(oauth_version)
                            );


            // make the request

            ServicePointManager.Expect100Continue = false;

            var postBody = "screen_name=" + Uri.EscapeDataString(screen_name);//
            resource_url += "?q=" + query;
            HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(resource_url);
            request.Headers.Add("Authorization", authHeader);
            request.Method = "GET";
            request.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";


            WebResponse response = request.GetResponse();
            string responseData = new StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream()).ReadToEnd();
        }
```

While trying to run the code I get an exception at request.GetResponse():

```
The remote server returned an error: (401) Unauthorized.
```

I tried to use the same code to get user statuses ("https://api.twitter.com/1.1/statuses/user_timeline.json") and it worked fine. Does anyone know what is causing the exception?

## edit

I tried to run the following curl command and it also worked well:

```
curl --get 'https://api.twitter.com/1.1/search/tweets.json' --data 'q=ENGAGE' --header 'Authorization: OAuth oauth_consumer_key="xxx", oauth_nonce="xxx", oauth_signature="xxx", oauth_signature_method="HMAC-SHA1", oauth_timestamp="xxx", oauth_token="xxx", oauth_version="1.0"' --verbose
```

I tried to make the equivalent WebRequest object but haven't managed to run it successfully. If possible, I would also appreciate if anyone could show how to make the WebRequest object which makes the same request as above curl command.

Thank you!

Comment: Meybe this link can help http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18803532/need-help-about-search-and-streaming-api-of-twitter

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved the problem. It turns out that the sequence of parameters in base string is important. It is the same with other Twitter API GET requests.

This is an example of correct base string:

```
var baseFormat = "oauth_consumer_key={0}&oauth_nonce={1}&oauth_signature_method={2}" +
                            "&oauth_timestamp={3}&oauth_token={4}&oauth_version={5}&q={6}";

            var baseString = string.Format(baseFormat,
                                        oauth_consumer_key,
                                        oauth_nonce,
                                        oauth_signature_method,
                                        oauth_timestamp,
                                        oauth_token,
                                        oauth_version,
                                        query
                                        );
```

whereas the following returns 401 Unauthorized:

```
var baseFormat = "q={6}&oauth_consumer_key={0}&oauth_nonce={1}&oauth_signature_method={2}" +
                            "&oauth_timestamp={3}&oauth_token={4}&oauth_version={5}";

            var baseString = string.Format(baseFormat,
                                        oauth_consumer_key,
                                        oauth_nonce,
                                        oauth_signature_method,
                                        oauth_timestamp,
                                        oauth_token,
                                        oauth_version,
                                        query
                                        );
```

Below is the complete working method which returns search results:

```
private void searchTweetsWithQuery(string query)
        {
            var oauth_token = xxx;
            var oauth_token_secret = xxx;
            var oauth_consumer_key = xxx;
            var oauth_consumer_secret = xxx;

            // oauth implementation details
            var oauth_version = "1.0";
            var oauth_signature_method = "HMAC-SHA1";

            // unique request details
            var oauth_nonce = Convert.ToBase64String(
                new ASCIIEncoding().GetBytes(DateTime.Now.Ticks.ToString()));
            var timeSpan = DateTime.UtcNow
                - new DateTime(1970, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, DateTimeKind.Utc);
            var oauth_timestamp = Convert.ToInt64(timeSpan.TotalSeconds).ToString();

            // message api details
            var status = "Updating status via REST API if this works";
            //working example: https://dev.twitter.com/discussions/12758
            var resource_url = "https://api.twitter.com/1.1/search/tweets.json";
            var screen_name = "ENGAGEinterreg";
            // create oauth signature

            var baseFormat = "oauth_consumer_key={0}&oauth_nonce={1}&oauth_signature_method={2}" +
                            "&oauth_timestamp={3}&oauth_token={4}&oauth_version={5}&q={6}";

            var baseString = string.Format(baseFormat,
                                        oauth_consumer_key,
                                        oauth_nonce,
                                        oauth_signature_method,
                                        oauth_timestamp,
                                        oauth_token,
                                        oauth_version,
                                        query
                                        );



            baseString = string.Concat("GET&", Uri.EscapeDataString(resource_url), "&", Uri.EscapeDataString(baseString));

            var compositeKey = string.Concat(Uri.EscapeDataString(oauth_consumer_secret),
                                    "&", Uri.EscapeDataString(oauth_token_secret));

            string oauth_signature;
            using (HMACSHA1 hasher = new HMACSHA1(ASCIIEncoding.ASCII.GetBytes(compositeKey)))
            {
                oauth_signature = Convert.ToBase64String(
                    hasher.ComputeHash(ASCIIEncoding.ASCII.GetBytes(baseString)));
            }

            // create the request header
            var headerFormat = "OAuth oauth_consumer_key=\"{3}\", oauth_nonce=\"{0}\", oauth_signature=\"{5}\", oauth_signature_method=\"{1}\", " +
                               "oauth_timestamp=\"{2}\",  " +
                               "oauth_token=\"{4}\", " +
                               "oauth_version=\"{6}\"";

            var authHeader = string.Format(headerFormat,
                                    Uri.EscapeDataString(oauth_nonce),
                                    Uri.EscapeDataString(oauth_signature_method),
                                    Uri.EscapeDataString(oauth_timestamp),
                                    Uri.EscapeDataString(oauth_consumer_key),
                                    Uri.EscapeDataString(oauth_token),
                                    Uri.EscapeDataString(oauth_signature),
                                    Uri.EscapeDataString(oauth_version)
                            );


            // make the request

            ServicePointManager.Expect100Continue = false;

            var postBody = "screen_name=" + Uri.EscapeDataString(screen_name);//
            resource_url += "?q=" + query;
            HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(resource_url);
            request.Headers.Add("Authorization", authHeader);
            request.Method = "GET";
            request.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";


            WebResponse response = request.GetResponse();
            string responseData = new StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream()).ReadToEnd();
        }
```